# Algorithm to detect when and where a point will exit a rectangle area

Tags: algorithm, scala, gps, gis

Assume that we have a rectangle or a square and we know the x,y coordinates of its corners (4 corners).

Also assume that we have a point inside that square for which we know its coordinates (x,y), its speed (km/h), its heading (heading is measured in directional degrees, 0 for north, 180 for south and so on) and the time point it has these attributes (epoch time in seconds).

How can we calculate the time point (epoch time in seconds) in which the point will exit the rectangle as well as the coordinates (x,y) of the exit ?

Comment: Are the sides of the square/rectangle aligned with the directions of the compass?

Comment: Yes, they are aligned.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Time and motion in spherical coordinates is a topic documented well in textbooks and on line.

Comment: If you have a problem with code, post the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (per the posting guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find what edge is intersected first. Make equations for moving along both coordinates and calculate the first time of intersection.

Note that for geographic coordinates you might need more complex calculations because "rectangle" defined by Lat/Lon coordinates is really curvy trapezoid on the Earth surface. Look at "Intersection of two paths given start points and bearings" chapter on [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get travel time.

```
vx = V * Cos(heading + Pi/2)   //for y-axis north=0
vy = V * Sin(heading + Pi/2)

x = x0 + vx * t
y = y0 + vy * t

//potential border positions    
if vx > 0 then
   ex = x2
else
   ex = x1

if vy > 0 then
   ey = y2
else
   ey = y1

 //check for horizontal/vertical directions
if vx = 0 then
return cx = x0,  cy = ey, ct = (ey - y0) / vy

if vy = 0 then
    return cx = ex, cy = y0, ct = (ex - x0) / vx


//in general case find times of intersections with horizontal and vertical edge line
  tx = (ex - x0) / vx
  ty = (ey - y0) / vy

 //and get intersection for smaller parameter value
 if tx <= ty then 
    return cx = ex, cy = y0 + tx * vy, ct = tx
 else
    return  cx = x0 + ty * vx,  cy = ey,  ct = ty
```

Comment: Putting your algorithm to the test in a flat surface and not a spherical one (earth), with x0 = 8.0, y0 = 2.0 (I assume that these are the coordinates of the point), t = 1508327031 (epcoh seconds for which the point has these attributes), V = 5.0 km/h and heading = 90.0 (directional degrees), x1 = 0.0, x2 = 10.0, y1 = 0.0, y2 = 10.0 (I also assume that these values are the min/max X/Y coordinates of the rectangle) the results I take are cx = 4.0, cy = 0.0 and ct = 0.89 which are wrong.

Comment: @AlJenssen Did you convert 90 degrees to a heading in radians?

Comment: Even if I convert it to radians, the results are incorrect.

Comment: Did you convert the velocity to the correct units? (If the distances are measured in kilometers, you'd still need to convert the velocity from km/h to km/s by dividing by 3600.)

Comment: @Al Jenssen  Direction 90 degrees assumes that vx or vy *(depending on chosen coordinate system)* is zero , so one intersection coordinate must coincide with starting point coordinate, but your result definitely shows  direction about **26**  degrees. Perhaps you implemented some expression wrong.