# Smarter way to evaluate reflection in a table

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, optimization, geometry

Suppose I have a ball moving in a table and I want to evaluate the reflections it will do in the walls.

Suppose it will have a given movement vector:

[image]

I know the end position is the red dot, following this logic. For simplicity, let's suppose the table is 4x2 and centered in (0,0). My code to evaluate the position is:

```
ball.position += ball.movement;
if(ball.position.x > 2)       ball.position.x = 2 - (ball.position.x - 2);
else if(ball.position.x < -2) ball.position.x = -2 + (-2 - ball.position.x);
if(ball.position.y > 1)       ball.position.y = 1 - (ball.position.y - 1);
else if(ball.position.y < -1) ball.position.y = -1 + (-1 - ball.position.y);
```

I'd like to know if there is a shorter / faster / smarter way to approach this evaluation, instead of 4 `if-else` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for `if-else` statements can be reduced to two by using [`Mathf.Abs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Abs.html) so a check e.g.

```
if(x < -2)
else if(x > 2)
```

simply becomes

```
if(Mathf.Abs(x) > 2)
```

then in both cases you can use [`Vector2.Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html). And in roder to instantly also clamp the position use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

```
ball.position += ball.movement;

if(Mathf.Abs(ball.position.x) > 2) ball.movement = Vector3.Reflect(ball.movement, Vector2.up);
if(Mathf.Abs(ball.position.y) > 1) ball.movement = Vector3.Reflect(ball.movement, Vector2.right);

// and for instantly also clamp the position
ball.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(ball.position.x, -2f, 2f), Mathf.Clamp(ball.position.y, -1f, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to change `movement` component after reflection. So

```
ball.movement.vx = abs(ball.position.x) > 2 ? -ball.movement.vx: ball.movement.vx;
similar for y
```

---

Also note that more reliable model includes [preliminary calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808841/algorithm-to-detect-when-and-where-a-point-will-exit-a-rectangle-area/46809063#46809063) of reflection moment instead of post-factum changing